# Pass a catalog via variable into an SQL connection manager in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, ssis-2012

I have an execute SQL task that captures the latest snapshot database that is created on another server.  I want to put that new Snapshot name into my connection manager so I can move the data I need from it into a data warehouse. I have the new database name saved as a variable.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Since I have the snapshot/catalog name how can I populate that into my connection manager so that it changes whenever my snapshot changes?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use an expression to change the properties of the connection manager.  Expressions can be a very powerful tool in SSIS.  Check out [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-property-expressions-in-sql-server-integration-services/) for a good read on expressions in SSIS.  (The section entitled, "Accessing a Component’s Properties" might be exactly what you need.)

Comment: That's what I am trying to do but when I change it to my expression all my data flow tasks begin to fail because the catalog hasn't been populated yet. I populate it at the very first of the SSIS job through an SQL query?